# How to show Wifi password of an unknown wifi network in batch?

Tags: batch-file, networking

I want to find my WiFi password of my router. But I forgot it and I just bought a new PC and trashed out the old one. I had to come to work to write this! So far, I only have this code that finds the WiFi password of the saved WiFi:

```
@echo off
set WifiName="MyNetwork"
netsh wlan show profiles "%WiFiName%"
pause >nul
exit /b
```

I don't want to install any programs, because I am using my PC for work, and my boss doesn't let me install programs other than my work programs. Any help would be appriciated!

Comment: If you have code that shows the password, what is the question?

Comment: You should be able to connect to your router via a network cable and reset the password, possibly even show the current one, but that depends on the web UI of your router.

Comment: If by "unknown network" you mean "my own wifi network that I'm unable to connect to because I don't know the password" then the answer is that that is not that simple. If a computer could simply *show* the password to any wifi router in its vicinity, why would we use passwords then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All routers can be reset to their original factory settings, typically by using a paper clip, to push some switch inside a small hole at the back. Do that, and you will be able to reconfigure your router.